# Optimizing the maven builds in eclipse with multiple projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, module

I am looking for a way to speed up rebuilds in eclipse.

Some background: we have a relatively large project, about 177 pom files altogether, approximately 150 maven modules. The full build without the test takes about 15-20 minutes, with tests - close to 6 hours. Which is a PITA when you debug or refector. We have several active branches (and need to switch between them rather often, sometimes several times per day). Local branches are always X.X-SNAPSHOT versions (which seems to be important).

Most of the time you are not making changes to all of the projects, just few you work on. So there is a lot of room for optimization.

I guess my ideal scenario would be to select certain projects that are to be pulled from package repository and never build locally unless I explicitly say so. Can this be achieved?

---

Things I tried:

1. Importing only subset of the modules. Partially helps, but maven still checks all dependencies, which inevitably results in half the modules in the project being checked anyways, even though none of them changed. Partial success.
2. Only checking out the projects from source control that I am going to work with. Builds are blazingly fast, because maven pulls binary dependencies from the corporate repo or ~/.m2 cache instead of building them. Working with SVN and Git becomes rather difficult, because you don't have all the source checked out. Partial success.
3. Disabling automatic builds and building everything from command line with -am -pl options, specifying the project(s) that were updated. Helps when you need to build a large change (i.e. after merge), but (a) this is cumbersome and (b) when you turn on automatic builds again you are taxed.
4. Suggesting that we break down that huge repo into individual services and base libraries and moving into different source control repos. Got "yeah right" from management. Probably not going to happen.

Is there anything else that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

After being stuck with these 4 options for a while, I found out that moving to Idea and fiddling with the Maven cache settings (literally, pointing IDE cache to ~/.m2) made the pains a bit more tolerable. Still the solution is far from being satisfactory. I hope this helps.